# p:commandButton onclick function not invoked in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces, onclick

```
<p:commandButton id="changepwd" value="Change Password" type="button"
  onclick="changepwdPanel.show()" update="dialog,messages" appendToBody="true" />
```

This button displays a `<p:dialog>`. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: do you have any dialog effects or modal attribute set true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
</f:facet>
```

in `<h:head>`, 
I had similar issue and it worked for me.